# How to save Microsoft Excel Pagination on Mac?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Protected Microsoft Excel Spreadsheet. Every time I open it and try to print, Excel wants to split into 8 pages. If I cancel the print and drag the dashed line to the right, then I can make it print in just 2 pages. Unfortunately this information is not saved when I save the file.

Is there any way to save this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try dragging the page break as you have, then create a custom view that saves the current state as 'normal' or some other name. It may be you print settings or page setup and margins are overriding things.

View>Custom Views>

[image: Custom View Dialog]

Then Name it

[image: Name the view]

Saving custom views are a great way to assert a page setup in a macro

But I would further investigate page setup and margins as well, because that may be the cause of the problem

Comment: That's interesting; how do you create a custom view?

Comment: sorry, this is Excel 2003, and the same can be done in the later versions

Comment: And so it can. Thank you very much. This seems to do it!